# Why do I never get any results in my async.map?

Tags: javascript, async.js

I am using `asyncjs` to `map` through an array.  Here is the first version of my code:

```
    async.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], async function(url) {
        console.log(url);
        return Promise.resolve(url);
    }, (err, results) => {
        if (err) console.log("ERR", err);
        console.log("RESULTS", results);
    });
```

The urls log out, but I never get the `results` to log out.  I have also tried it with the old school callback

```
    async.map([11, 12, 13, 14, 15], (url, callback) => {
        console.log(url);
        callback(url);
    }, (err, results) => {
        if (err) console.log("ERR", err);
        console.log("RESULTS", results);
    });
```

In this case, the urls still log out, `results` is `undefined`.  How do I get this working?  What am I missing?

Comment: your second example works with `callback(null, url);` the first i need to test

Comment: I forgot that `err` is the first argument in the `callback`.

Comment: your first code works without errors: https://runkit.com/teammmate/5a107da960129800128ac4d1

Comment: Does the actual code that you use do any async operations? I have experienced some weird behaviour when using async.js with synchronous functions